# How to secure data in html select object filled with Ajax from MVC database

Tags: model-view-controller

sorry for my english

I am filling the select element with values ajax from the database. Then I want to verify that the data that changed when the user posted the form as a result of changing the value values of the select object through the browser is really the data I filled.

How can I solve this with a general coding in infrastructure?
Instead of going to the database and checking each filled data one by one, I want to hold the data I filled in the select tag and check the verification with this data in the post operation.

[mvc fill select changed value example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uuIh.jpg)

Comment: One way is to use referential integrity in the database. Then you can't save any data to the database that isn't valid.

Comment: yes it is true, but even if the listed data is the correct value for the foreign key, it may be wrong on a user basis. There is a red product for user A, while there should be no red product for user B.

Comment: You could always call the same API again and check it against the posted JSON.